# how to close inappbowoser in cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-3, ngcordova

Apk file

```
<a class='btn btn-primary' onclick="window.open('http://somedomain/payment.php', '_system', 'location=yes');" >Payment</a>
```

Paymnet.php file

```
<div class="login-wrap">
    <div class="login-html">
        <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-in" checked><label for="tab-1" class="tab"></label>
        <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-up"><label for="tab-2" class="tab"></label>
        <div class="login-form">
             <form action="" method="post" class="sign-in-htm">
        <input type="hidden" name="furl" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="surl" value="">

                <div class="group">
                    <label for="name" class="label">Name</label>
                    <input id="name" name="fullname" type="hidden" class="input" value="">
                </div>
                               <div class="group">
                    <label for="email" class="label">Email</label>
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="hidden" class="input" value="">
                </div>
 <div class="group">
                    <label for="email" class="label">Price</label>
                    <input type="hidden" name="amount"  value="">
                </div>

                <div class="group">
                    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" name="submit">
                </div>



            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
require "instamojo.php";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$api = new Instamojo\Instamojo('token', 'api', 'https://test.instamojo.com/api/1.1/');

$name=$_POST['fullname'];
$amount=$_POST['amount'];
$email=$_POST['email'];


    try {
        $response = $api->paymentRequestCreate(array(
            "purpose" => 'h-fm',
            "name" => $_POST['fullname'],
            "amount" => $_POST['amount'],
            "send_email" => false,
            "email" => $_POST['email'],
            "redirect_url" => "http://test.com/"
            ));
       // print_r($response);
       $redirect=$response['longurl'];

?>
       <script type="text/javascript"> 
            window.location.href = "<?php echo $redirect;?>" ;

</script> 

    <?php }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        print('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
    }
    ?>
```

How to redirect from web app to mobile app. payment is working fine. I want to give close button . I tried window.close . its not working . I tried ref.close(). its not working. Please help me to resolve this issue .

Comment: And you cannot redirect to mobile app.You can redirect from mobile app to your web app.

Answer (score 0):

Simply using the close() function of inappbrowser plugin its provide the facility to close the app .

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://unitedwaymassbay.org/', '_blank', 'location=no');
ref.close();
```

here the reference of function please read it [inappbrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/)